# How to redirect people after they register using django registration

Tags: python, django, django-registration

```
url(r'^register/$',
    RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=CustomRegistrationForm,
                             success_url='/profile'),
    name='registration_register',
    success_url='/profile'),
```

I have the following in my urls.py.

How do I redirect people after they register using django registration 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect will be issued to the path specified by `RegistrationView.get_success_url`, which should be `RegistrationView.success_url` which you've specified when constructing the view function.

You can review [`RequestView.form_valid`](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/aafb10048c77a80d93526ae4f2c2ce648399ee8b/registration/views.py?at=v1.0#cl-81) for more details.

Comment: So how do I change the success_url?

Comment: Either supply a different value for the `success_url` keyword argument to `RegistrationView.as_view` or extend `RegistrationView` and configure the `success_url` attribute.

Comment: I tried doing that: 
                       url(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(
                           form_class=CustomRegistrationForm,
                           success_url=reverse('profile')),
                           name='registration_register'),
 but it doesn't work

Comment: Looks like your doing everything right. Can you make sure `RegistrationView.form_valid` is called (`CustomRegistrationForm` received valid data) and that you have a view mapped to `reverse('profile')`. Are you getting any specific errors?